# How to make incremental slide within .pull-left[] in xaringan?

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

I divide a **xaringan** slide into two columns using `.pull-left[]` and `.pull-right[]`. But I realize that I cannot make each item incremental within each column. Is there any way to make the items incremental inside `.pull-left[]` or `.pull-right[]`? Or any other ways?

Comment: Its not possible to make incremental slides within pull-left or pull-right

Comment: Is there any alternative option to make incremental with two column slide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's not possible to create incremental slides using `--` within `.pull-left[]` or `.pull-right[]`, you can create similar behaviour, by making additional slides like this,

```
---
title: "Incrementals in pull-left or right" 
output: xaringan::moon_reader
---



## Incremental points

.pull-left[
- point one
]

.pull-right[
This is some random text. This is some random text. This is some random text.
This is some random text. This is some random text.
]

---

## Incremental points

.pull-left[
- point one

- point two
]

.pull-right[
This is some random text. This is some random text. This is some random text.
This is some random text. This is some random text.
]

---
```